# Passing Table Type Input Parameter To Stored Procedure in Execute SQL Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to call a stored procedure from Execute SQL Task in SSIS. The stored procedure accepts two table type variable which I am constructing in another Execute SQL Task and storing in object type of variable.
Since I need to pass object type of variable I am using ADO.NET connection manager.
Also since I am using ADO.NET connection manager, I cannot pass the input parameter as ? mark in direct input and I need to write expressions.
But expressions do not support object type variable.
What is the way out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the native ADO/OLE source components. You'll have to use a Script Component acting as a Source and use .NET to create

Relevant bits from my [SQL TVP post](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html)

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
System.Data.DataTable dataTable = null;

// note that my data table does not have to be the same
// as my UDTT, nor do my columns have to have the same name
// Types-yes. Ordinal, probably so
dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable("Sample");
dataTable.Columns.Add("tweep", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dataTable.Columns.Add("have_met", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));

// add rows to my data table but really, this could be any source
dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "billinkc", true });
dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BrentO", true });
dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "buckwoody", false });

// Hooray for #sqlsat35 and meeting Jen & Sean
dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MidnightDBA", true });

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = null;
System.Data.DataSet results = null;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = null;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    connection.Open();
    command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("TwitterAdd");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = connection;

    // Assigning a table valued parameter looks much like any other parameter
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter tvp = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", dataTable);

    // this is the only special sauce (not required but helpful)
    tvp.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
    tvp.TypeName = "dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE";

    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        // pseudo logic here
        while(dataReader.Read())
        {
            MyBuffer.AddRow();
            MyBuffer.Col1 = dataReader["Col1"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks billinkc. I am preparing the object variables in execute sql task by connecting to ADO.NET connection manager. But when I am reading the read only variables in script task the table in the dataset shows up as empty. When I execute the same in SSMS I am able to see the data in the table type variable. I am reading the variable in dataset and using first table to pass to the SP. I am not sure why the object is coming as null.

Comment: It seems the execute sql task is not able to populate the object variable with the data as I cannot see the data in watch by setting breakpoint. It's a select statement fetching some rows from couple of tables which are joined. Not sure what the problem is. I have set the Result Set to full result set. Changing it to single row throws an error "Unable to populate result columns for single row result type. The query returned an empty result set"

Comment: Sorry for adding multiple comments. I am adding as I am getting closer to get it working. Now I am facing a weird problem. I have a variable in which I am storing a link (https://abcd/xyz/ijk.aspx) from DB in a execute SQL task. Now when I am using it in creating the object variable in another execute sql task I am getting "incorrect syntax near https:" error. I am not sure this has anything to do with any escape sequence or need any special handling.

Comment: Well, this is really screwing my head. I could by-pass the slash problem somehow but there is a new problem. In the expression of execute sql task if I write like this,
"select "+[User::UserName]+" as Username, employeeid from employee where alias = "+[User::Alias]
It throws me an error Incorrect column 'soumyadeb' which is evaluated value of username variable.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks billinkc for the input. I have finally managed to make it work. I have used Script task to pass the object variables to stored procedure and do my job. One observation I want to share which I could not logically explain.
My object variable is having the below structure.
{
employeeid int,
dept_id int,
empname varchar(100),
Gender varchar(50)
}
Remaining part in the next comment.

Comment: In execute sql task, I was trying to prepare the object by querying the database and storing the full result set in an object type of variable. But when I am doing like below,
select e.employeeid as employeeid, 2 as dept_id, e.empname as empname, 'Male' as Gender from employee e
I was getting invalid column '2' error (it was coming for 'Male' value as well).
I went ahead and passed these as null in execute sql task and after that I added a script task and updated these values from variables. It worked.
Any idea why this happens.